# Вывод строки с подставновкой в неё значений из переменных вместо ключей

Tags: php

Вопрос простой для тех кто знает!
Есть у меня строка в переменной:

```
 $str = 'Добрый день %username% вы авторизованны как %profilename%';
```

Как можно вывести эту строку что бы вместо "флажков" (%username% %profilename% и пр. подобные)

подставлялась нужная мне информация из других переменных, я понимаю это можно сделать через несколько str_replace но, кажется я видел более элегантный способ при помодщи prinf или чего то похожего в php?

это мне надо для некоторых моментов связанных с языковыми версиями в приложении так как в одной и той же фразе на разных языках порядок слов меняется

Comment: Ну есть старая добрая интерполяция, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437121/php-string-interpolation-syntax/43437427. Хотя проценты придется заменить.

Comment: @bipll а ну так то да, но проблема в том что у меня переменные с текстом они в отдельных файлах вроде eng.php rus.php, а вставлять в них надо не посредственно перед выводом что бы не нарушать структуру, я просто когда то давно видел как что то такое применяют, вот и подумал)

Comment: @dantelol именно с помощью [str_replace()](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/160047209eb253ed631da16ee43ab2122c9b73ca) это и делается, при чём с помощью однократного её вызова _(а ни нескольких, как вы подумали)_, т.к. str_replace() работает как со строками, так и с массивами.

Comment: @dantelol а то чо подставлять у вас в каком виде - массив, одноименные переменные?